# Why does Firefox 4 transform every list-item bullet into '0.'

Tags: css, html-lists

So the thing is that in Firefox 4 the list-style bullets transform to '0.'
No matter which list-style-type I choose (except circle, disc and square).

[image: Screenshot]

All the other browsers don't seem to have a problem with it.
Well except for IE then.

You guys have any idea how I can solve this problem?

**EDIT**
=> http://icid-testing.heroku.com/

Comment: I'm using FF4 now and that I've certainly not seen that happen. Shan Plourde is probably right, it's your css.

Comment: Using FF4, Ubuntu 10.10, this issue is non-repro.

Comment: I can repro this at the provided URL on FF4 and confirm that it looks okay on IE8.

Comment: I'm seeing what you mean now, this is weird.

Comment: @Mad, that was my first thought, but FF has supported `hiragana` since version 1.0: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/list-style-type

Comment: @Lord Torgamus: Yep. sorry realized, edited comment too soon! I'm suspecting a bug now!

Comment: Never mind, some other guy solved it. 'overflow: hidden' was the problem <.<

Comment: @Icid, argh, that was the next line of CSS I was going to test! You can post and then accept your own answer, though, so that this question appears solved to future SO users.

Comment: Hah, you know what. You should give the answer and then you'll get awesome SO points 8)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to work if you just remove `overflow: hidden;` from the `ol li` rule.

```
ol li {
    list-style: hiragana inside none;
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    /* overflow: hidden; */
    white-space: nowrap;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you used a tool such as Firebug or Web Developer to see what CSS classes are getting selected and applied? Perhaps there is a CSS class that is getting applied and that has higher precedence, i.e. something with !important, or a CSS rule that is more specific that's overriding your CSS rules.

Comment: Hmm nope, just double checked it. And there's only one list-style declaration in my css file.

Comment: -1, this is a debug strategy, and as such it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @lcid, interesting, I see the Japanese Hiragana characters on FF 4 the same way that you do, although it renders fine on Chrome. IE 8 seems to render it as a standard numeric list. Not sure if styling lists this way will work, perhaps the FireFox and IE rendering engines don't support Hiragama as a list-style-type?  Do the the Hiragana characters render on FF if you type them into the page source? If not, perhaps you'd have to resort to using images.

Comment: It's supported by Firefox (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/css/list-style-type) and I don't care much about IE. They will have to do it with numbers. Anywho, the problem is already solved ;) Thanks tho'